# How do I extract the content from zend mail imap?

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap, zend-mail

I'm trying to write a script which downloads all mail in a certain folder without a custom flag, let's call the flag $aNiceFlag for now; after I've fetched a mail I want to flag it with $aNiceFlag. However before tackling the flag problem I've got a problem to extract the content i need from the mail right now.

This is the information I need:

- Sender (email and name if possible)
- Subject
- Receiver
- Plain text body (if only html is available I will try convert it from html to plaintext)
- Time sent

I can easily get the subject by using `$mailObject->subject`. I'm looking at the [Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) but it's a bit confusing for me.

Here's my code right now, I'm not supposed to echo out the content but that's just for now while testing:

```
$this->gOauth = new GoogleOauth();
$this->gOauth->connect_imap();
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(&$this->gOauth->gImap);
$storage->selectFolder($this->label);
foreach($storage as $mail){
    echo $mail->subject();
    echo strip_tags($mail->getContent());
}
```

I'm accessing the mail using google oAuth. `$this->label` is the folder I want to get. It's quite simple for now but before making it to complex I want to figure out the fundamentals such as a suitable way to extract all above listed data into separate keys in an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the headers for sender, receiver and date quite easily using the same technique you used for the subject, however the actual plaintext body is a bit more tricky, here's a sample code which will do what you want

```
    $this->gOauth = new GoogleOauth();
    $this->gOauth->connect_imap();
    $storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(&$this->gOauth->gImap);
    $storage->selectFolder($this->label);
    // output first text/plain part
    $foundPart = null;
    foreach($storage as $mail){
        echo '----------------------<br />'."\n";
        echo "From: ".utf8_encode($mail->from)."<br />\n";
        echo "To: ".utf8_encode(htmlentities($mail->to))."<br />\n";
        echo "Time: ".utf8_encode(htmlentities(date("Y-m-d H:s" ,strtotime($mail->date))))."<br />\n";
        echo "Subject: ".utf8_encode($mail->subject)."<br />\n";

        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail) as $part) {
            try {
                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
                    $foundPart = $part;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        if (!$foundPart) {
            echo "no plain text part found <br /><br /><br /><br />\n\n\n";
        } else {
            echo "plain text part: <br />" .
                    str_replace("\n", "\n<br />", trim(utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode(strip_tags($foundPart)))))
                ." <br /><br /><br /><br />\n\n\n";
        }
    }
```